# how to write several spaces in a cell with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using the PHPExcel library, and I want to write in a cell several spaces. 
eg "NAME: X             PHONE : Y" 
but it always deletes spaces and leaves me just one.

Comment: What Writer are you using? Simply setting the cell value as a string with multiple spaces works perfectly well for the Excel5 and Excel2007 Writers.

Comment: I would post some relevant code so maybe someone can see what is going wrong.

Comment: i m using this code :
"$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');"

Comment: If you're using Excel2007, then there shouldn't be any problems with multiple spaces, and I have just tested this with your example string from the question. If you open the file you're generating in MS Excel, it should show all 13 spaces between `X` and `PHONE`. I'd only expect this to be reduced to displaying a single space in HTML